# Жесты в ListView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть список(ListView,переделывать на RecyclerView не вариант), на каждом пункте весит  три действия:

- Свайп(справа на лево)
- Нажатие по пункту
- Нажатие по кнопке в пункте

Сделать это у меня получилось, но результат не совсем устраивает. Свайп хоть и прикреплен ко всему пространству пункта, не срабатывает если он проходит над кнопкой. Если с кнопки снять OnClickListener, то свай работает прекрасно.

Рекомендации на сайте андройдовском прочитал, но пока что не особо помогли. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным, или просто умеет организовывать кучу жестов на пункте списка, поделитесь как правильно "повесить" все жесты на пункт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло вот это:

```
mButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Немного подкрутив, пригодилось